# Certificate loaded from Cert Store causes issues in ASP.NET Kestrel server

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssl, certificate, cert-manager

We have a backend running ASP.NET Core and we are trying to get it to use a certificate stored in the Current User / Computer --> Personal certificates store. We have alredy implemented an alternative which allows the user to specify a .pfx + password --> works fine.

The problem arises when loading from the Windows Cert Store. We are finding the certificate itself using its thumbprint which is supplied by the user. The Cert is clearly found and all looks good when inspectin the certificate object in the debugger
[image]

CNs match with the URL I am trying to listen to and everything - all good. No exceptions either, it seems OK. The problem though is that the pages will not load with this configuration.I just get "Connection closed"
[image]

If I remove the certificate and change to http it works fine with the listen URL. Same thing if I use certificate path (.pfx) + password and https url, it works fine. I don't understand what is happening here. Why is it not working when I clearly seem to find the certificate from the store?

My only suspicion is that it somehow has to do with access to the certificate and our IT's some odd policy which enforces me to make up some ADDITIONAL password when adding a certificate to a store:
[image]
This is NOT the certificate password, this can be anything I choose and I am not sure when I am supposed to give this when accessing certificates, especially HOW and WHEN in code? Anyone got any idea on what this is and if it could be the cause of my problems?
Thanks!

Comment: That prompt for a password on installing suggests you have strong key protection enabled, so you're creating a password required to use the private key.  Since Kestrel doesn't have that password, it can't use the private key.  AFAIK, Kestrel doesn't support PIN-or-password protected private keys from the system stores.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @bartonjs. That pretty much summarizes my suspection too, though I never knew the name of it. I believe you are right, this "Strong key protection" does seem to be what is haunting me... I found the security policy for it under Local Policies -> Security options -> System Cryptography: Force strong key protection... and as expected I cannot change it and it is set to "Users must enter a password each time they use a key"...